# Issues opening an XML file in Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-9

I have been trying to open an XML file in Explorer without success. Gives me "error processing resource" The xml file is shown below.

Any idea why I cannot open it?
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<one:Row>
    <one:Cell>
        <one:OEChildren>
            <one:OE>
                <one:InsertedFile pathSource="H:\Dashboard.pdf" preferredName="Dashboard.pdf" />
            </one:OE>
            <one:OE>
                <one:T>
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </one:T>
            </one:OE>
        </one:OEChildren>
    </one:Cell>
    <one:Cell>
        <one:OEChildren>
            <one:OE>
                <one:T>
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </one:T>
                <one:T>
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </one:T>
            </one:OE>
        </one:OEChildren>
    </one:Cell>
</one:Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an undefined namespace (i.e. "one:").

Try adding a namespace declaration for "one:" like follows:

```
one:Row xmlns:one="blah"
```